# Running a command when a CD/DVD/BD inserted

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, mount, automounting

This seems like a simple question to me, but after two nights of searching and tinkering, I haven't been able to find anything promising.

I am running a headless Ubuntu server. I want to be able to stick a DVD or BD in my external drive, and have the server immediately begin ripping it.

I read about HAL, but it looks like that's no longer supported, so I didn't investigate very far.

It seemed like UDEV was the way to go, but upon experimenting, I found that UDEV doesn't seem to generate events when an optical disk is inserted-- only mounted.

So I gave autofs a try, and haven't had much luck with that either. It doesn't mount when I put the disk in, and I get errors on startup complaining about "mountall: Event failed".

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend looking at 
http://sudocode.blogspot.com/2009/06/auto-rip-audio-cds-in-ubuntu-server.html

Worked for me

Comment: This uses `ivman`, which I can't find on Ubuntu Oneiric. Is there a workaround or alternative for this?